# Separar texto com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma string e preciso separar o nome da rua, bairro, cidade e estado.

**string:**

```
Rua tal Muniz, 124 - ramones, Sapucaia - SP
```

Como eu posso fazer usando JavaScript?
(Pode ser uma solução com ou sem a utilização da biblioteca jQuery)

Comment: O endereço vem sempre nesse formato aí ou pode ter variações?

Comment: vem sempre nesse formato

Comment: Poderia colocar exatamente como está o seu array, junto com o código que tentou fazer? Em qual informação ficou com dificuldade?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a informação vem assim em texto corrido eu precisaria das informações separadas

Comment: `.split(",")` e subsequente `split(" - ")` talvez resolva o seu problema. Só você sabe dizer

Comment: Eu não fiz o codigo ainda, eu preciso de um norte pra seguir não faço ideia de como começar preciso de dicas só

Comment: E o array que citou, onde fica?

Comment: Você pode começar tentando dividir a string nas vírgulas, depois dividir no hífen.

Comment: É importante lembrar que nessa ideia se qualquer uma das informações já tiver uma virgula ou hifen cria-lhe um problema.

Comment: @Josimara Apenas uma breve explicação da minha edição. No caso você comentou que a informação vinha em texto então acredito que você não possuia de fato um array e sim uma string. Outro ponto é que você colocou "javascript ou jquery" esse "ou" pode permitir uma má interpretação ao leitor, que é a ideia que jquery não é javascript, sendo que, ele nada mais é do que um conjunto de funções em javascript. Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma é utilizando a posição dos separadores como abaixo:

```js
const separar = endereco => {
  let posicao = endereco.indexOf(',');
  const rua = endereco.substring(0, posicao).trim();
  let aux = endereco.substring(posicao + 1).trim();
  posicao = aux.indexOf('-');
  const numero = aux.substring(0, posicao).trim();
  aux = aux.substring(posicao + 1).trim();
  posicao = aux.indexOf(',');
  const bairro = aux.substring(0, posicao);
  aux = aux.substring(posicao + 1).trim();
  posicao = aux.indexOf('-');
  const cidade = aux.substring(0, posicao).trim();
  aux = aux.substring(posicao + 1).trim();
  posicao = aux.indexOf('-');
  const estado = aux;
  
  return {
    rua,
    numero,
    bairro,
    cidade,
    estado,
  }
}

console.log(separar('Rua tal Muniz, 124 - ramones, Sapucaia - SP'));
```

Outra forma é utilizando a seguinte expressão regular:

```
/^(.+),(.+)-(.+),(.+)-(.+)$/gm
```

Da seguinte forma:

```js
const ENDERECO = /^(.+),(.+)-(.+),(.+)-(.+)$/gm;

const separar = endereco => {
  const match = ENDERECO.exec(endereco);

  return {
    rua: match[1],
    numero: match[2],
    bairro: match[3],
    cidade: match[4],
    estado: match[5],
  }
}

console.log(separar('Rua tal Muniz, 124 - ramones, Sapucaia - SP'));
```

- `^` assegura que a posição está no início da linha
- Captura o grupo `(.+)`:

  - `.+` combina qualquer caractere (exceto terminadores de linha);
  - O quantificador `+` combina entre 1 ou vezes ilimitadas, quantas vezes forem possíveis;
- `,` combina o caractere literal `,`;
- Captura o grupo `(.+)`:

  - `.+` combina qualquer caractere (exceto terminadores de linha);
  - O quantificador `+` combina entre 1 ou vezes ilimitadas, quantas vezes forem possíveis;
- `-` combina o caractere literal `-`;
- Captura o grupo `(.+)`:

  - `.+` combina qualquer caractere (exceto terminadores de linha);
  - O quantificador `+` combina entre 1 ou vezes ilimitadas, quantas vezes forem possíveis;
- `,` combina o caractere literal `,`;
- Captura o grupo `(.+)`:

  - `.+` combina qualquer caractere (exceto terminadores de linha);
  - O quantificador `+` combina entre 1 ou vezes ilimitadas, quantas vezes forem possíveis;
- `-` combina o caractere literal `-`;
- Captura o grupo `(.+)`;
- `$`  assegura que a posição está no final da linha.

Answer (score 0):

Se a **string** seguir sempre esse padrão, você pode tentar algo assim:

```js
var endereco = 'Rua tal Muniz, 124 - ramones, Sapucaia - SP';
var separado = endereco.split(',');

var rua     = separado[0].trim();
var bairro  = separado[1].split('-')[1].trim();
var cidade  = separado[2].split('-')[0].trim();
var estado  = separado[2].split('-')[1].trim();

console.log('Rua: ' + rua);
console.log('Bairro: ' + bairro);
console.log('Cidade: '+ cidade);
console.log('Estado: '+ estado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o código abaixo. Testando aqui, funciona. Antes de fazer a quebra do texto por *","* faça uma reposição do *"-"* por uma vírgula.

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Rua tal Muniz, 124 - ramones, Sapucaia - SP";
    str = str.replace("-", ",");
    var res = str.split(",");
    //variável res agora é um array que você pode percorrer com um loop ou posições fixas
}
```